# How to link brew-cask make to brew cmake

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I did brew cask install cmake, but when I was about to brew install something, brew wants to install cmake.
How can I let brew know that there's already cmake available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t. Homebrew and Homebrew Cask are separate projects that install things in different ways. Homebrew assumes you don’t have `cmake` if it’s not installed through Homebrew so it’ll refuse to install even if a `cmake` binary exists in the `PATH`. It has no way to ensure this `cmake` binary is indeed the `cmake` it’s looking for.

A hacky way would be to edit the formula you want to install (`brew edit <formula>`); remove the line with `depends_on "cmake" => :build`; install it (`brew install <formula>`); then add the line back again.